# how to scrape a dynamic table from wunderground

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble scraping a table with python.
Example is the big table in a weather history website with all the numbers every hour.

```
url= "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/va/arlington-county/KDCA/date/2019-1-25"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
my_table = soup.find("table", class_ = "mat-table cdk-table mat-sort ng-star-inserted")
print(my_table)
```

I got the class attribute by inspecting the html. The problem is I get None... It's like it is non existing. I checked that I get 200 as a response from the website so this is not the problem.
Am I missing something here?

Thanks,

Comment: Always look in your soup first - therein lies the truth. The content can always be slightly to extremely different from the view in the development tools.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I did not know that.

Comment: if you print the "soup" variable, there is no table there. they formatted the table using div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is constructed dynamically by `JavaScprit` from data that comes from an API endpoint.

You can query that endpoint and reconstruct the table.

Here's how:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

endpoint = "https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KDCA:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=20190125&endDate=20190125"

response = requests.get(endpoint).json()["observations"]
weather_data = sorted(response, key=lambda k: k["valid_time_gmt"])

header = [
    "Time", "Temperature", "Dew Point", "Humidity", "Wind",
    "Wind Speed", "Wind Gust", "Pressure", "Percip.", "Conditions",
]

table = []
for item in weather_data:
    row = [
        datetime.fromtimestamp(item["valid_time_gmt"]).strftime('%I:%M %p'),
        item["temp"],
        f'{item["dewPt"]} °F',
        f'{item["rh"]} %',
        item["wdir_cardinal"],
        item["wspd"],
        f'{item["gust"] if item["gust"] else 0} mph',
        f'{item["pressure"]} in',
        f'{item["precip_total"] if item["precip_total"] else "0.0 in"}',
        item["wx_phrase"],
    ]
    table.append(row)

print(tabulate(table, headers=header, tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Sample output:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
|   Time   | Temperature | Dew Point | Humidity | Wind | Wind Speed | Wind Gust | Pressure | Percip. |  Conditions   |
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
| 06:52 AM |     37      |   22 °F   |   54 %   | WNW  |     10     |   0 mph   | 29.91 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 07:52 AM |     36      |   21 °F   |   55 %   |  NW  |     6      |   0 mph   | 29.92 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 08:52 AM |     35      |   21 °F   |   57 %   |  W   |     7      |   0 mph   | 29.95 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 09:26 AM |     35      |   21 °F   |   57 %   |  W   |     6      |   0 mph   | 29.95 in | 0.0 in  | Mostly Cloudy |
| 09:52 AM |     35      |   22 °F   |   59 %   |  W   |     5      |   0 mph   | 29.96 in | 0.0 in  | Mostly Cloudy |
| 10:52 AM |     36      |   22 °F   |   57 %   | VAR  |     5      |   0 mph   | 29.98 in | 0.0 in  |    Cloudy     |
| 11:52 AM |     35      |   21 °F   |   57 %   | WNW  |     9      |   0 mph   | 30.0 in  | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 12:52 PM |     35      |   21 °F   |   57 %   |  NW  |     10     |   0 mph   | 30.0 in  |  0.79   | Mostly Cloudy |
| 01:52 PM |     35      |   21 °F   |   57 %   | WNW  |     5      |   0 mph   | 30.02 in | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 02:52 PM |     37      |   22 °F   |   54 %   | WSW  |     8      |   0 mph   | 30.04 in | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 03:52 PM |     40      |   22 °F   |   49 %   |  W   |     14     |  18 mph   | 30.04 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 04:52 PM |     41      |   19 °F   |   41 %   |  W   |     17     |  21 mph   | 30.06 in | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 05:52 PM |     43      |   20 °F   |   40 %   | WNW  |     14     |  23 mph   | 30.06 in | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 06:52 PM |     41      |   18 °F   |   40 %   |  W   |     16     |   0 mph   | 30.07 in | 0.0 in  | Mostly Cloudy |
| 07:21 PM |     42      |   19 °F   |   40 %   |  NW  |     16     |  24 mph   | 30.07 in | 0.0 in  | Mostly Cloudy |
| 07:52 PM |     43      |   20 °F   |   40 %   |  NW  |     18     |  24 mph   | 30.08 in | 0.0 in  | Partly Cloudy |
| 08:52 PM |     43      |   12 °F   |   28 %   |  NW  |     9      |  20 mph   | 30.09 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 09:52 PM |     42      |   11 °F   |   28 %   | WNW  |     13     |   0 mph   | 30.09 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 10:52 PM |     40      |   10 °F   |   29 %   |  NW  |     13     |   0 mph   | 30.12 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 11:52 PM |     37      |   12 °F   |   36 %   | NNW  |     10     |   0 mph   | 30.14 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 12:52 AM |     36      |   8 °F    |   31 %   | NNW  |     12     |   0 mph   | 30.16 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 01:52 AM |     35      |   8 °F    |   33 %   | NNW  |     9      |   0 mph   | 30.17 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 02:52 AM |     33      |   7 °F    |   34 %   |  NW  |     13     |   0 mph   | 30.18 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 03:52 AM |     32      |   7 °F    |   35 %   | NNW  |     5      |   0 mph   | 30.18 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 04:52 AM |     32      |   7 °F    |   35 %   |  N   |     5      |   0 mph   | 30.2 in  | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
| 05:52 AM |     31      |   7 °F    |   37 %   | NNW  |     6      |   0 mph   | 30.22 in | 0.0 in  |     Fair      |
+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to retrieve the API key from Wunderground? I would like to obtain API keys for approximately 19 stations in order to perform what you did on the answer

Comment: @Zesima29 just use your Dev Tools in your favorite browser. Check out the XHR tab and you should see something like this https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/37.782/-122.422/forecast/wwir.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&language=en-US&units=e

Comment: Okay, thanks that was very helpful idk you could access the backend of a website like that.  This is the API that I got from the Dev Tools, but I get errors when I try to get historical data from another date for example 2023-04-30 could you help me on what would be the syntax I'm getting JSONDecodeError   https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/current?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&stationId=KNYNEWYO1585&numericPrecision=decimal&format=json&units=e

Comment: Can you please ask a question. This won't work thru the comments here.

Comment: Thanks for the help and yes, here is the question, I modified your code a bit as a template for the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433218/how-do-i-add-dates-to-a-url-to-retrieve-historical-data-from-a-website