# How Do I add dates to a URL to retrieve Historical data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I've this API `https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/current?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&stationId=KNYNEWYO1585&numericPrecision=decimal&format=json&units=e` and I'm trying to retrieve data from 2023-04-30

However, I get the following error

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-873917b622c8> in <module>
     10 endpoint = f"https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apiKey}&stationId={station_id}&format=json&units=e&date={start_date}&endDate={end_date}"
     11 
---> 12 response = requests.get(endpoint).json()["observations"]
     13 weather_data = sorted(response, key=lambda k: k["epoch"])
```

Can anyone help me with the proper syntax for the endpoint? I believe the mistake lies here because the API link works for the current time but not for the specific date I'm trying to retrieve data for. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

apiKey = "e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525"
station_id = "KNYNEWYO1585"
start_date = "2023-04-30"
end_date = "2023-04-30"

endpoint = f"https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apiKey}&stationId={station_id}&format=json&units=e&date={start_date}&endDate={end_date}"

response = requests.get(endpoint).json()["observations"]
weather_data = sorted(response, key=lambda k: k["epoch"])

header = [
    "Time", "Temperature", "Dew Point", "Humidity", "Wind",
    "Wind Speed", "Wind Gust", "Pressure", "Precip.", "Conditions",
]

table = []
for item in weather_data:
    row = [
        datetime.fromtimestamp(item["epoch"]).strftime('%I:%M %p'),
        item["temp"],
        f'{item["dewpt"]} °F',
        f'{item["humidity"]} %',
        item["winddir"],
        item["wspd"],
        f'{item["wgust"] if "wgust" in item else 0} mph',
        f'{item["pressure"]} in',
        f'{item["precip_total"] if "precip_total" in item else "0.0 in"}',
        item["wx_phrase"],
    ]
    table.append(row)

print(tabulate(table, headers=header, tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Comment: Is that your real API key? You should redact it in your question and change it now.

Comment: Using an API is not web scaping. Web scraping is what you do when there's no API, so you extract the data from an HTML web page.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of this API?

Comment: I don't but the issue also arises when I attempt to scrape via HTML, as I only receive empty headers on my table when I do it. So someone suggested that I should try retrieving the data through an API endpoint instead, so I used the dev tools to find the API endpoint and that's what I'm currently doing. You can even try it yourself. The actual website I'm referring to is: https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/KNYNEWYO1585/table/2023-04-30/2023-04-30/daily

Comment: Without the documentation, it's anyone's guess what the correct parameters are to specify the start and end dates.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint you're querying is wrong. And so is the payload.

To get all the table readings for a given day, you need this:

```py
import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

payload = {
    "stationId": "KNYNEWYO1585",
    "format": "json",
    "units": "e",
    "date": "20230430",
    "numericPrecision": "decimal",
    "apiKey": "e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525",

}
endpoint = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/history/all?"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.57",
}

data_points = (
    requests
    .get(endpoint + urlencode(payload), headers=headers)
    .json()["observations"]
)

table = []
for data_point in data_points:
    table.append(
        [
            datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data_point["epoch"]).strftime("%I:%M %p"),
            data_point["imperial"]["dewptAvg"],
            data_point["imperial"]["tempAvg"],
            data_point["humidityAvg"],
            data_point["winddirAvg"],
            data_point["imperial"]["windspeedAvg"],
            data_point["imperial"]["windgustAvg"],
            data_point["imperial"]["pressureMax"],
            data_point["imperial"]["precipRate"],
            data_point["imperial"]["precipTotal"],
            data_point["uvHigh"],
            data_point["solarRadiationHigh"],
        ]
    )

columns = [
    "Time",
    "Dew Point °F",
    "Temp °F",
    "Humidity %",
    "Wind",
    "Wind Speed mph",
    "Gust mph",
    "Pressure in",
    "Precip Rate in/hr",
    "Precip Total in",
    "UV",
    "Solar Radiation W/m^2",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=columns)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
```

Using the above, you can reconstruct the table (*to whatever liking you might have*).

```
+----------+----------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+------+-------------------------+
| Time     |   Dew Point °F |   Temp °F |   Humidity % |   Wind |   Wind Speed mph |   Gust mph |   Pressure in |   Precip Rate in/hr |   Precip Total in |   UV |   Solar Radiation W/m^2 |
|----------+----------------+-----------+--------------+--------+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+------+-------------------------|
| 06:04 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |    351 |              0.5 |        2.8 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:09 AM |           50.7 |      51   |           99 |     48 |              1.1 |        2.8 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:14 AM |           50.7 |      51   |           99 |    289 |              0.4 |        3.2 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:15 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |    257 |              2   |        2.7 |         29.78 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:23 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |     15 |              0   |        2.6 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:34 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |    252 |              0.7 |        2.6 |         29.78 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:36 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |     29 |              0   |        2.2 |         29.78 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:48 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |     21 |              1.3 |        2.8 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:53 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |    285 |              0.6 |        2.1 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 06:59 AM |           50.6 |      50.9 |           99 |    297 |              1.9 |        4.8 |         29.79 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:09 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |     66 |              0   |        2.7 |         29.77 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:15 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |    352 |              2   |        5.1 |         29.77 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:22 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |     64 |              2.5 |        2.7 |         29.77 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:28 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |      4 |              1.6 |        4.3 |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:34 AM |           50.5 |      50.8 |           99 |    261 |              0.5 |        3.1 |         29.77 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:39 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |     66 |              0   |        2.5 |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:44 AM |           50.5 |      50.8 |           99 |    107 |              0.5 |        3.5 |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:48 AM |           50.5 |      50.8 |           99 |      0 |              1   |        3.5 |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 07:54 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |    300 |              0   |        3.4 |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 08:02 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |    270 |              1.3 |        4   |         29.76 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 08:09 AM |           50.2 |      50.5 |           99 |    274 |              1.9 |        5.8 |         29.75 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |
| 08:11 AM |           50.4 |      50.7 |           99 |     77 |              2.2 |        3.5 |         29.75 |                0    |              0    |    0 |                     0   |

AND A WHOLE LOT MORE ...
```